# How to add validation so that the form does not accept blank spaces?

Tags: javascript, validation

```
$scope.addTodo = function () 
{
    $scope.todos.push({text:$scope.formTodoText, done:false});
    $scope.formTodoText = '';
};
```

Comment: please add the language tag

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow, I've fixed formatting of your code for you and added the language tag (this is JavaScript, isn't it?), but you really have to add some context to it, not just some code. Do you use a framework or vanilla JS? What does the sited code do? Is that method the only way to modify you todos? Please take a https://stackoverflow.com/tour and read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Best regards

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$scope.addTodo = function () {
    if ($scope.formTodoText.replace(/\s/g,'').length > 0) {
        $scope.todos.push({text:$scope.formTodoText, done:false});
        $scope.formTodoText = '';
    }
};
```

Remove all spaces in the value and check if there's anything left.

Answer (score 0):

I would do like this:

```
`$('#MyForm input').blur(function()
 {
     if( !$(this).val() && $(this).val() != "" ) {
           $(this).parents('p').addClass('warning');
     }
 });`
```